# "The exam date" vs. "the exam day"

Tags: word-choice, nouns

> - I will send you my proposal two months before the exam **date**.
> - I will send you my proposal two months before the exam **day**.

Which one is more correct?

Comment: They mean the same thing.  Neither is more correct than the other.

Comment: Here they are the same. In general though 'day' refers to the day of the week (eg Tuesday) and 'date' refers to the month date and year.

Answer (score 3):

As Jim said, both variations are acceptable, and they are functionally interchangeable.

Stylistically, I prefer ***date*** over ***day*** in the relatively formal context of your example sentence. Here's what sounds most natural to my ears:

> I will send you my proposal two months **prior to** the exam **date**.

Again, both of your original examples are grammatically correct. I'm just musing on nuances of style here.

Something else to consider: in your example, "exam date" and "exam day" are basically interchangeable as the objects of a preposition. They barely differ. However, it's less simple when we cast them as the *SUBJECT* of a clause/sentence. "Exam day" is acceptable (similar to *game day*, *Christmas day, graduation day*, even *Monday* & *today*) and is interchangeable with "the day of the exam".
On the other hand, "exam date" does not work as a sentence subject; instead, you could say "the date of the exam", but note the difference in meaning ("date" = the calendar number, "day" = the occasion/event).

Comment: Something else just occurred to me. In your example, "exam date" and "exam day" are basically interchangeable as the objects of a preposition. They barely differ. However, it's less simple when we cast them as the SUBJECT of a clause/sentence. "Exam day" is acceptable (similar to game day, Christmas day, graduation day, even Monday & today) and is interchangeable with "the day of the exam". On the other hand, "exam date" does not work as a sentence subject; instead, you could say "the date of the exam", but note the difference in meaning ("date"=the calendar number vs."day"=the occasion/event)

Comment: I took the liberty of incorporating your comment into your answer since I thought it added some worthwhile observations that shouldn't be stuck down in an afterthought.